# Some of my ng aliases are not working for angular in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, angular-cli

So i just started watching the angular beginner course on pluralsight and when i tried to do what was done which is `ng build --prod --source-map` it gave me this  `Error: Unknown argument: prod. I did it without the --source-map` part as well but still it gave the same error as above.

I got this issue with dry run alias as well but i didnt care much because the complete command `--dry-run` worked fine.

I tried to do dry run using alias => `ng g c user-component -d` and it gave me Error: `Unknown argument: d`.

But it runs fine if i just type `ng g c user-component --dry-run`.
I dont know why its not working for some of the commands. I Searched for a solution but could not find one that matches.

Comment: Did you read the CLI docs (e.g. https://angular.io/cli/build)? Are you using the matching version to the course you're trying to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to know that --prod flag is now deprecated and that after angular 12.0 ng build will automatically build in production . But i still found no solution for the -d alias of --dry-run flag. I suppose it also got deprecated . But still i cudnt find anything that said it was deprecated so if anyone knows the new alias for --dry-run please do comment)))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, I ran into this too and have wondered why the -d alias disappeared. It was always very convenient, so I have no idea why it was removed.